# Manifest classpath filter in maven-jar-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-jar-plugin

Can I exclude some artifacts from classpath that generates by `<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>` option?

For example, I have some dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.group1</groupId>
  <artifactId>lib11</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.group1</groupId>
  <artifactId>lib12</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.group2</groupId>
  <artifactId>lib21</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

At now, my classpath entry in **MANIFEST.MF** is:

```
Class-Path: lib/lib11.jar lib/lib12.jar lib/lib21.jar
```

I want exclude some groupIds of my dependencies list and take entry in this form:

```
Class-Path: lib/lib21.jar
```

How I can do it?

Comment: BTW: What do you use the `Class-Path` for?

Comment: @JFMeier I use class-path to specify all used libraries and other app modules in my runnable jar. Some modules at production stage are located in another directory rather lib. I disabled copy this dependencies to lib directory and manual specified they in class-path. I want to delete from class-path entries like lib\lib11.jar because already define it manual with correct path like lib11.jar without prefix, for example.

Comment: Interesting ... I thought that nowadays people use fat jars. Or wars/ears in an Application server.

Comment: @JFMeier It’s not a fat jar. All dependencies are located outside jar. And it’s a desktop javafx application.

Answer (score 0):

When adding a tag `scope` with a value `provided` to unnecessary dependencies, they disappear from classpath, as required.
For an example from the question:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.group1</groupId>
  <artifactId>lib11</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.group1</groupId>
  <artifactId>lib12</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```